# setLayoutParams dip values

Tags: android, android-layout, pixel, density-independent-pixel

I am trying to use the method setLayoutParams in order to specify the graphical parameters of my table layout, but I am not sure whether the method setLayoutParams takes pixel values, or dip values, especially that in java the values stored seem to be pixel ones, for examples if I declare these two variables:

```
private int blockDimension = 50; 
private int blockPadding = 2;
```

And then call the method :

```
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( (blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding) * numberOfColumnsInMineField,blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding) );
```

Are they considered as being pixels or are they converted once passed to the method ? Then if they aren't, how can I set dip values in java ?

Comment: method setLayoutParams takes pixel values

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr Yatsykiv, but if I want to define values in dip in java, do I have to convert them anyway to pass them to the setLayoutParams method ?

Comment: yes, if you have values in dp you must convert it to px (see answer below) and after that put it to setLayoutParams method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes pixels. To convert dp to pixels you can use this:

```
public int getPx(int dimensionDp) {
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dimensionDp * density + 0.5f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want that values in dip you have to multiply it for the density of the screen
You can get it this way:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
```

Comment: Ok thanks, you mean I should be doing something like int blockDimensionDipValue = blockDimension * density ?

Comment: Yes but cast blockDimension to float and the result to int